# VLOOKUP Macro to reformat data between sheets preserving the connection to the source

Tags: performance, vba, excel

Hello I'm relatively new to VBA and I have this macro to VLookup information into corresponding cells in the sheet that works, the issue is that it depends on a For Loop to iterate through 10s of thousands of rows. This is taking a significant amount of time to iterate and I know I'm asking a good amount of it but I feel like there's a faster way than how I have it currently. Any help would be appreciated!

```
Sub Test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Calc_Setting As Long
Calc_Setting = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

On Error Resume Next
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0



Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim MARCws As Worksheet, FTws As Worksheet
Dim MARCLastRow As Long, FTLastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim dataRng As Range

Set MARCws = wb.Sheets("MARC-MARA Pivot Values")
Set FTws = wb.Sheets("Forecasting Template")

MARCLastRow = MARCws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
FTLastRow = FTws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set dataRng = MARCws.Range("A4:Q" & MARCLastRow)

For x = 4 To MARCLastRow
    On Error Resume Next
    FTws.Range("C" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 2, False)
    FTws.Range("E" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 3, False)
    FTws.Range("F" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 4, False)
    FTws.Range("G" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 5, False)
    FTws.Range("H" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 6, False)
    FTws.Range("I" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 7, False)
    FTws.Range("J" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 8, False)
    FTws.Range("K" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 9, False)
    FTws.Range("L" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 10, False)
    FTws.Range("M" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 12, False)
    FTws.Range("AZ" & x) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value, dataRng, 17, False)
    FTws.Range("BA" & x) = (FTws.Range("AZ" & x).Value / 30)
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = Calc_Setting

End Sub
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to have the formulas built in to the sheet? I don't see anything here that requires the use of VBA. You should use tables that automatically fill in formulas as the tables expand. It might help to describe *what* you are trying to do and not just *how* you are doing it. This will help people help you.

Comment: Using the formulas in the sheet would be faster, but I'm designing this such that the formulas are inaccessible and thus unbreakable for the user, since building the formulas into the sheet has proved unreliable due to human error. One idea that I had that perhaps might work that would be if I could have macro run the vlookup formula into the first row's relevant cells and could then have another statement copy and paste to the last row, what do you think about that?

Comment: That's what a table does. The table will automatically copy the formulas down the row. Select your data and Press **CTRL+T** to make a table.

Comment: Are you using FTLastRow anywhere?

Comment: As a further frame challenge: Excel can protect/hide formulas to prevent accidental edits. Format Cells -> Protection -> Locked,Hidden; and then menu Review -> Protect -> Protect Sheet to prevent displaying or editing the formulas. Similar feature in Libreoffice/Openoffice.

Answer (score 6):

**Code Style**

Avoid multiple variable declarations in a single line, like `Dim MARCLastRow As Long, FTLastRow As Long, x As Long`.

It is generally not recommended to include the variable type in the variable name (e.g. `ws` in `MARCws`), as variable names should be self-explanatory / self-documenting. Although I know this and don't do this in any other language, I still find myself doing this in VBA. For some reason I find it to increase readability in VBA (while I find it harmful in other languages). Just something to consider.

---

**Functionality**

If you run into an error (`On Error GoTo 0`), `Application.Calculation = Calc_Setting` will not be executed, therefore the original calculation setting will not be restored.

It seems to me that this `Sub`'s functionality could be more easily replicated without VBA, using formulas inside the worksheet. I'd expect this to improve performance as well. I'm assuming there's a specific reason to do this in VBA, so I'll take a look at the performance next.

---

**Performance**

You're doing too much work. Instead of calling `Vlookup` 10 times with different column values you should only look for the desired row once. Once you have the address / range object you can easily replicate your current functionality by stepping through the row with the [`Range.Offset`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.offset) property.

For getting and setting cell values I would recommend using `Range.Value2` instead of `Range` (withough `Value`) or `Range.Value`. `Range.Value2` refers to the range's underlying "real" value, withough any formatting applied to it. More detailed discussion [here](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/). `Range.Value2` is slightly faster than `Range.Value` and is generally preferable for most use cases, as you probably don't want to deal with cell formatting if you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you. Though using the formulas in the worksheet would be faster, I'm designing a process that is designed to have no end thought for the user and also no possibility for an end user to somehow break it because there will be 100s of end users using the tool independently and any one error could be critical. One idea that I had that perhaps might work that would be somewhat "having the formulas in the sheet" and would only iterate once would be if I could have the first rows containing either the vlookup formula or range.offset, I could then have another statement copy and paste to lastrow

Comment: What do you think about that? and would you have any ideas on how to achieve that?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're suggesting. I'd recommend starting out with the suggestions I made regarding the performance.

Comment: My point was that if I use the Range.Offset property that improves performance but then the loop still iterates 50k times. Is there a way to have the loop iterate once but then instead of it pasting values it pastes the formulas such that I can then do a copy paste with my range being row n+1 to the last row? Wouldn't that improve runtime quite significantly?

Comment: Well if you're just copying formulas, you probably don't need VBA for this use case. If you want to do it in VBA, I don't see a way around iterating over every row. Unless of course there's some patterns in your data I don't know of.

Answer (score 2):

Each line within the `for` loop executes a `VLOOKUP` even though failure by the first `VLOOKUP` statement guarantees that each subsequent statement will also fail.  It would be more efficient to check for 'success' only once per loop and then grab the remaining data after that.

So, below is an option that uses the `MATCH` function within a helper function.  The function returns `True` and the `Range` row offset if a match is found.  Even for scenarios where a match is found every time, the approach below will save time.  `VLookup` is not called upon to evaluate a very large lookup range 11 X '10s of thousands rows' *times* more than necessary.

````
Sub Test()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Calc_Setting As Long
Calc_Setting = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

On Error Resume Next
If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
On Error GoTo 0



Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Dim MARCws As Worksheet, FTws As Worksheet
Dim MARCLastRow As Long, FTLastRow As Long, x As Long
Dim dataRng As Range
Dim dLookupRange As Range

Set MARCws = wb.Sheets("MARC-MARA Pivot Values")
Set FTws = wb.Sheets("Forecasting Template")

MARCLastRow = MARCws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
FTLastRow = FTws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Set dataRng = MARCws.Range("A4:Q" & MARCLastRow)

'Setup a Range to use specifically by the MATCH function
Set dLookupRange = MARCws.Range("A4:A" & MARCLastRow)

Dim dMatchingRowOffset As Long

For x = 4 To MARCLastRow
    
    'Find the row of interest once...then grab all the data using Range.Cells
    'rather than VLookup.  Otherwise, move onto the next row
    If TryFindRowOfInterest(FTws.Range("A" & x).Value2, dLookupRange, dMatchingRowOffset) Then
        
        FTws.Range("C" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 2).Value2
        FTws.Range("E" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 3).Value2
        FTws.Range("F" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 4).Value2
        FTws.Range("G" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 5).Value2
        FTws.Range("H" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 6).Value2
        FTws.Range("I" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 7).Value2
        FTws.Range("J" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 8).Value2
        FTws.Range("K" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 9).Value2
        FTws.Range("L" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 10).Value2
        FTws.Range("M" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 12).Value2
        FTws.Range("AZ" & x).Value = dataRng.Cells(dMatchingRowOffset, 17).Value2
        FTws.Range("BA" & x).Value = (FTws.Range("AZ" & x).Value2 / 30)
        
    End If
Next x

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = Calc_Setting

End Sub

Private Function TryFindRowOfInterest(ByVal pLookupValue As Variant, ByVal pDataRange As Range, ByRef pOutRangeRowOffset As Long) As Boolean
    
    pOutRangeRowOffset = -1
    
On Error Resume Next
    pOutRangeRowOffset = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(pLookupValue, pDataRange, 0)
    
    TryFindRowOfInterest = pOutRangeRowOffset > -1
End Function


```
````

Comment: I think, something in relation to the screen updating or xl calculation settings is causing this code to have no output at all, would you have any idea what the fix may be?

Comment: A couple things: 1) Put a breakpoint at a point inside the loop and see if it is ever 'hit'.   2) comment out all the Application settings and see if it changes the results.   FWIW,  I ran this code against some fake data that I thought would be _like_ your dataset,  and it generated the results I thought I should expect.  Note: if you pass `dataRng` rather than `dLookupRange` into the `TryXXX` predicate function...it would always return `False`.

Comment: That entire IF statement can be made smaller (don't repeat yourself) - just use a Loop.

Comment: I put the breakpoint within the loop and it wasn't hit. A breakpoint just outside the loop hits but for some reason the if statement is returning false

Comment: So, the next step would be to sort out why the `Match` function is not returning `True` when you would expect it to.  Probably best to create a single statement that you can execute in isolation, and experiment with the parameters until you find the issue.

Comment: It can really only be one of two things:  The `pDataRange` parameter should be a single column Range (e.g., "A4:A20000") of the `MARCws` worksheet.  The `pLookupValue` parameter should be a valid value and be located somewhere in `MARCws` worksheet's A column.  If both of those conditions are met, the `Match` function will return a value - and the helper function will return `True`.  Hope that helps you find the issue.